# Modifying IE's download journal

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

I'm having problems deleting entried from IE's downloads journal.

So I've found a file which responsible for storing this information. In my case file located here:

> AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\IEDownloadHistory\index.dat

You can also obtain its location from registry - the key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\Cache\Extensible Cache\iedownload` and the variable is `CachePath`. If IE is running this file is locked. It is important for me to modify this file while IE is running because I'm trying to achieve that from a Browser Helper Object.

I also was trying to clean up this list using some of the WinInet methods: FindFirstUrlCacheEntry, FindNextUrlCacheEntry and DeleteUrlCacheEntry - but I'm not quite sure if those what I'm exactly looking for.

Since there are not so many information about this problem I was trying to use everything I've found relative...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate this entries using  FindFirstUrlCacheEntryEx/FindNextUrlCacheEntryEx  with parameters lpszUrlSearchPattern = L"iedownload:" and dwFilter = 0XFFFFFFFF.